# Implicit class can't apply to self-type?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, traits

I've defined a class and an implicit class:

```
class User
implicit class RichUser(user: User) {
  def hello = println("hello")
}
```

Following code is working well:

```
val user = new User
user.hello
```

But following code is not compilable:

```
trait UserTrait {
  this: User =>

  this.hello // can't compile !!!
}
```

Why can't it compilable, and how to fix it?

---

Update:

Sorry, it doesn't compile in IntelliJ IDEA, and I didn't try with `scalac`. Thanks for all.

[image: idea-error]

Comment: Compiles for me in 2.10.2 and 2.11.7.

Comment: I does compile for me on 2.11.

Comment: When you get an error from the compiler, then always include the exact error message in your question; don't just say "it can't compile". The error message contains important information to find out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Do you know which Scala SDK are you using from IntelliJ?

Comment: To me it compiles with Scala 2.11.7, but the IDE highlighter shows an error as shown on your screenshot. Seems like a Scala plugin highlighter error.

Comment: Reported as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9302

Comment: This is why I trust the compiler more than an IDE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not nice, but you can always call the implicit explicitly (pun intended)

```
trait UserTrait {
  this: User =>

  implicitly[RichUser](this).hello 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no compilation error in IDEA with this style. And from other comments, the original code is OK with `scalac`, but has errors with IDEA